# La tecla Enter no ejecuta el programa, solo hace un salto de linea, porque puede ser?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

Gente!!
estoy usando el Sublime text 3 para python 3.7. Hago un programa, lo ejecuto, no me arroja ningun error.
me pide ingresar un numero(por que asi es el programa) lo ingreso,le doy enter para que lo ejecute, y en lugar de ejecutarlo me hace un salto de pagina.
es como que dentro de los commandos del "enter" no estuviera "ejecutar"

Puede ser? me explico?

Comment: SublimeText no soporta stdin por defecto,  puedes instalar [sublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) o ejecuta el script en la consola/CMD directamente.

Comment: tengo instalado el sublimeREPL,

Comment: Por descartar cosas, ¿el programa se ejecuta correctamente si lo ejecutas en la consola/cmd?

Comment: si, es mas en otros IDE me ejecuta bien el programita.